# Как поместить текст из html между тегами H1 в переменную php для дальнейшей отправки на почту

Tags: php, jquery

у меня есть каталог с продуктом
наименование продуктов разное и при нажатии кнопки заказать всплывает окно с формой куда в тег H1 уже javascript подставляет наименование продукта.
как мне вытащить текст между тегами h1 в перемеренную отправщика на php

http://itso-msk.ru/montazh_videonablyudeniya.html

Comment: сайт пишу сам, учусь, поэтому не пугайтесь

Comment: тег h1 находится на клиенте, чтобы отправить его на php(на сервер), вам нужно воспользоваться формой (<form> который шлет запросы get или post) либо с помощью js(jQuery) отправлять `ajax` запрос. Получать данные на сервере (php) и выполнять действия с ними.

Comment: я просто с ajax не очень, может подскажите?

Comment: даже не так
вот форма

Comment: между тегами span

Comment: <span class="compl_name_mod" id="komplekt">Комплект на 1 внутреннюю AHD камеры</span>